# Check raw response in ApiResponse

Tags: c#, refit

In Refit, is there anyway to get the raw HTTP response in ApiResponse object?

In my case, if response code is 200, it returns type *Person*. If the response code is 201, it returns with an *Error* response. I want to be able to deserialize the HTTP response content again if status code is 201.

I have read the following links, that's all to do with catch exception and do another deserialization. I'm already doing that in another case. But this case is different, there was no exception.

[How to handle the exceptions](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/issues/253)

[How to Handle Errors](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/issues/270)

[Disable Refit from hiding HTTP content in case response code wasn't 200 (ApiException)](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/issues/231)

Thanks in advance

Comment: actually, 201 is not an error code. We have 2xx --> sucesss, 3xx --> redirect, 4xx --> client error, 5xx --> server error

Comment: @VõQuangHòa, thank you for your reply. Yes, 201 is not an error. That's what the other party defined. If response code is 201, it comes with error details in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the response type to `HttpResponseMessage` or `string`.
See [this section](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#retrieving-the-response) in Refit README